# How to build dylib in XCode?

Tags: xcode, dylib, libtool-xcode

I have a library in source code, it builds in .a static library, but i need .dylib. So, i choose Mach-O-Type in "Build Settings" as "Dynamic Library", but get error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mylib-fwducbhnvcuzuzaopjfimtlylztm/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mylib-fwducbhnvcuzuzaopjfimtlylztm/Build/Intermediates/mylib.build/Debug/mylib-osx.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mylib-osx.LinkFileList -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation -o /Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mylib-fwducbhnvcuzuzaopjfimtlylztm/Build/Products/Debug/libmylib-osx.a
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `f' in: -fobjc-link-runtime

libtool for some reason uses "-static" instead "-dynamic" flag... Compatibility version i've set. What do you think could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

object files (.o) could be extracted from archive file (.a) and then packed in .dylib with libtool or gcc